# Java recursive parent child hierarchy

Tags: java, java-8

```
class Employee{
  private String employeeId;
  private boolean isLeaf;
  private List<Employee> children;    
}

empl
   emp2
     emp2a
     emp2b
       emp2b1

   emp3
     emp3a
..
..
..
```

With the above hierarchy I want to create children of each employee.

Expected output:To get children of each parent

```
Map<String,Set<String>>

{"empl1",["emp2","emp2a","emp2b","emp2b1","emp3","emp3a"]}

{"empl2",["emp2a","emp2b","emp2b1"]}

{"empl2b",["emp2b1"]}

{"emp3",["emp3a"]}
```

Is this possible using existing Employee class structure?

Tried this, does not work though ,not sure how /where to stop the loop
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public void visitAllNodes(Employee emp){
   Map<String,Set> childMap = new HashMap<>();
       Map<String,Set> finalResult = 
   visitChildNodesTest(childMap,emp.getEmployeeId(),emp.getEmployees());
      
   }



private Map<String, List> visitChildNodesTest(Map<String, List> 
   parentChildMap, String parentEmpId,
    List<Employee> employees) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(employees)) {
    employees.forEach(employee -> {
      if (employee.getEmployees() != null) {
        getAndPut(parentChildMap,employee.getEmployeeId(),parentEmpId);
        visitChildNodesTest(parentChildMap, employee.getEmployeeId(), 
       employee.getEmployees());
      }
    });
  
  }
  return parentChildMap;
}

  private void getAndPut(Map<String, List> parentChildMap, String 
   employeeId, String parentEmpId) {
  if (parentChildMap.get(parentEmpId) == null) {
     List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
       ls.add(parentEmpId);
        ls.add(employeeId);
      parentChildMap.put(parentEmpId, ls);
    }  else {
      List ls = parentChildMap.get(parentEmpId);
        ls.add(employeeId);
        parentChildMap.put(parentEmpId, ls);
    }
  
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: well you have a problem here. Your target data structure allows only for 2 levels of depth. as far as i see emp2b1 is a grand child who got flattened to an immediate child . is that what you really need ?

Comment: Also @jena84 do you really mean children?  Or are they managedBy the employee or workFor the employee or friendsOf??

Comment: It looks like a tree, any reason why it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
class Employee {
    private String employeeId;
    public String getEmployeeId() { return employeeId; }
    private boolean isLeaf() { return children.size() == 0; }
    private List<Employee> children = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override public String toString() { return employeeId; }

    public Employee(String employeeId, Employee... children) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        for (Employee child : children)
            this.children.add(child);
    }

    public Set<Employee> descendants() {
        Set<Employee> descendants = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Employee child : children) {
            descendants.add(child);
            descendants.addAll(child.descendants());
        }
        return descendants;
    }
}
```

And

```
Employee emp1 =
    new Employee("emp1",
        new Employee("emp2",
            new Employee("emp2a"),
            new Employee("emp2b",
                new Employee("emp2b1"))),
        new Employee("emp3",
            new Employee("emp3a")));

Set<Employee> employees = new LinkedHashSet<>();
employees.add(emp1);
employees.addAll(emp1.descendants());
System.out.println(employees);

Map<String, Set<String>> map = employees.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(Employee::isLeaf))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmployeeId,
        e -> e.descendants()
            .stream()
            .map(Employee::getEmployeeId)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
[emp1, emp2, emp2a, emp2b, emp2b1, emp3, emp3a]
{emp3=[emp3a], emp2=[emp2b1, emp2a, emp2b], emp1=[emp2b1, emp3, emp3a, emp2, emp2a, emp2b], emp2b=[emp2b1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the basis of a solution is a recursive method like this:

```
public Set<String> getDescendantIds() {  
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (!isLeaf) {
        children.forEach(c -> result.add(c.employeeId));
        children.forEach(c -> result.addAll(c.getDescendantIds()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function like this in your Employee class should do that.

```
public Set<Employee> deepList(){
    Set<Employee> result = new HashSet<>();
    for(Employee e : children){
        result.add(e);
        for(Employee c : e.deepList()) result.add(c);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is a short test:

```
import java.util.*;

class Employee{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // only for testing
        Employee emp1  = new Employee("emp1");
        Employee emp2  = emp1.addChildren(new Employee("emp2"));
                         emp2.addChildren(new Employee("emp2a"));
        Employee emp2b = emp2.addChildren(new Employee("emp2b"));
                         emp2b.addChildren(new Employee("emp2b1"));
        Employee emp3  = emp1.addChildren(new Employee("emp3"));
                         emp3.addChildren(new Employee("emp3a"));

        emp1.deepListTest();
    }

    private String employeeId;
    private boolean isLeaf;
    private List<Employee> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public Employee addChildren(Employee employee){
        children.add(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    // only for test purposes as a set<String>
    public Set<String> deepListTest(){
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        for(Employee e : children){
            result.add(e.getEmployeeId());
            for(String c : e.deepListTest()) result.add(c);
        }
        if(!children.isEmpty()) System.out.println("{" + employeeId + ", [" + String.join(", ", result) + "]}");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{emp2b, [emp2b1]}
{emp2, [emp2b1, emp2a, emp2b]}
{emp3, [emp3a]}
{emp1, [emp2b1, emp3, emp3a, emp2, emp2a, emp2b]}
```

I hope this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks good, except just need to remove the last line of "`parentChildMap.put(parentEmpId, ls);`", then the code will work as you expected, it will stop automatically when it goes through all the nodes because you have the condiction of "isNotEmpty" there.

For more information to why need to remove that line because   `List ls = parentChildMap.get(parentEmpId);` already get the list reference, you just need to add the element to that list